# Why does Typescript accept a number value as a type?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I had a bug in my Angular 4 project where I had declared a variable:

```
debounce: 300;
```

instead of

```
debounce = 300;
```

So of course `this.debounce` was undefined before the fix.

Shouldn't Typescript give me an error in this case?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, you declared a variable or is this part of an object?

Comment: Part of a class like so:

    export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  model: any;

  searching = false;

  debounce: 300;
}

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you declare a variable with a type annotation of `300`, that means not only is the type numeric, but only the value `300` is acceptable:

```
var debounce: 300;
```

You will get an error if you attempt to assign, say, 200:

```
debounce = 200;
```

Switch on strict null checks, and the compiler will catch this kind of problem (you meant to assign the value, not a type annotation):

```
var debounce: 200;

// Strict null checks tells you here that you have done something strange
var x = debounce;
```

In this case, when you try to *use* the variable, strict null checks points out you never assigned a value - thus telling you that you made an annotation, not an assignment.

Answer (score 9):

You can basically pass (almost) anything as a value type to Typescript. So if you say:

```
class SomeClass {
  debounce: 300 | 500 | 700; 
  constructor() {
    this.debounce = 400;
  }
}
```

You will get a type error, since typescript is expecting the value for debounce to be `300`, `500` or `700`, not just any number. This means that you can be more specific about type annotations.

Answer (score 1):

That line is correct because unintentionally you have used `literal-types` ([for more information](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/literal-types.html)):

This [example](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/11/10/typescript-2-0-more-literal-types) helps you to understand how `literal-types` is used for restricting variables to **a finite set of possible values**:

```
let zeroOrOne: 0 | 1;

zeroOrOne = 0;
// OK

zeroOrOne = 1; 
// OK

zeroOrOne = 2;
// Error: Type '2' is not assignable to type '0 | 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's *not* a constant declaration. You have thought declared a variable and assigned a value implicitly typed. You are wrong. It's `number` type declaration that accepts specific values only.

```
debounce: 300;
```

and then assign it with

```
this.debounce = 300;
```

---

Typescript won't give you an error because it's syntactically correct, but runtime errors follows for `undefined` variables.